# Jenkins sh : wait for wget download to finish

Tags: shell-script, ssh, jenkins

I have a hard time to force wget command to wait until download finish's, problem occurs inside Jenkins `sh '''script place '''`. I have wrote the script in `.sh` file, where it runs without any issues, but after moving it into Jenkins other command in Jenkins executes before the download completes.

script I'm using looks like this

```
sh '''
                   ssh -i "${keyfile}" -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@myVM << ENDSSH
                   cd /toFolder
                   ls -l
                   echo
                   if [ -f *.zip ]
                      then
                      echo "zip file already exists. Aborting"
                      exit 1
                   fi
                   
                   wget ${URL} 
                   sleep 1
                   export ZIP_FILENAME=`ls *.zip`
                   echo run: deployment.sh -j $ZIP_FILENAME
                   echo
                   deployment.sh -j $ZIP_FILENAME
                   ENDSSH
                '''
```

for the sake of pasting this code here I have moved `ENDSSH` on the last line under deployment script to keep it inside the code block. (I know it should be far left of the script)

so my problem is that finding the file name which has to be deployed with deployment.sh is executed before download is completed.

Tried to use `wait` command, as well as `sleep`, which I do not think is a best way to do it, but wait command does not wait at all and sleep command works from time to time.  `curl` behavior is exactly the same.  any advices will be much appreciated, as long as I'm not with enough knowledge in Linux scripting.

Comment: I may misunderstood you first. So what is the real problem? The commands in this block run before wget finishes or the next sh block (not visible in your example) starting before this block finishes?

Comment: anything after `wget` runs before `wget`, or in the middle of download process. with `sleep` command it works from time to time

Comment: Then I don't see another possibility what I described in my answer. No shell starts a command before a previous one finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't send `wget` (or any command) into the background then the shell waits for the command to finish and doesn't start a next one earlier. That's how shell works. I think your real problem is the URL and the lack of quoting. If the URL has some special characters that can trick your shell, eg you may run something like this:

```
wget http://example.com&arg=1
```

which has the `&` char, so will start wget in the background (with a truncated URL), to prevent this use quotion marks:

```
wget "http://example.com&arg=1"
```

in your code with variable:

```
wget "${URL}"
```

Comment: yes, I'm aware of it, my  `URL` do not contains any characters except `/` forward slashe's

Comment: Anyway the quotation doesn't hurt.... it's a good practice, you have similar issues in the script, eg what if that zip file name contains a space or what if multiple zip files are there...

Comment: there will not be such cases in zip file, because I'm creating them myself.

Answer (score 1):

What happened here is that the commands in backticks were evaluated before the `<< ENDSSH` code was executed. This is correct behaviour (even if not expected!) because the heredoc is treated like a double-quoted string.

So for example, if there's no zip file before running your code, the `ls *.zip` will evaluate to an empty string before the heredoc code is run, and on execution this line will leave `ZIP_FILENAME` empty:

> ```
> ZIP_FILENAME=`ls *.zip`
> ```

The solution is to single-quote the heredoc label so that none of the expressions in the heredoc are evaluated before it's executed:

```
ssh ... << 'ENDSSH'
...
ENDSSH
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured out the solution myself, seems  script inside the `ENDSSH` does `async` calls of the script lines, moving anything below `wget` into another `ENDSSH` solved the issue.

```
sh '''
               ssh -i "${keyfile}" -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@myVM << ENDSSH
               cd /toFolder
               ls -l
               echo
               if [ -f *.zip ]
                  then
                  echo "zip file already exists. Aborting"
                  exit 1
               fi
               
               wget ${URL} 
               ENDSSH
            '''
sh '''
               ssh -i "${keyfile}" -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@myVM << ENDSSH2
               export ZIP_FILENAME=`ls *.zip`
               echo run: deployment.sh -j $ZIP_FILENAME
               echo
               deployment.sh -j $ZIP_FILENAME
               ENDSSH2
            '''
```

not the best and cleanest solutions, but maybe this can help someone facing same problem.

Comment: I still don't understand how that code can run "async"... Something is wrong here.

Comment: "_script inside the ENDSSH does async calls of the script lines_" - no it doesn't. But see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751626/100397) for the explanation, @redseven and ReViki

Comment: This can't work as the first here-document changes the directory while the second one does not.  If the second section finds a Zip file, it's not the one you fetched with `wget`.